# What happens under the hood when a commit statement is issued in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Suppose an update is made through a transaction, and then a commit statement is issued.

Which are all the internal processes are that happen under the hood in an Oracle server, after a commit statement?

Comment: This is an overly broad question. Welcome to SO but don't get disappointed if it gets closed. You can try to rephrase it, clarify it and narrow it a bit.

Answer (score 5):

1. SCN (System Change Number) is incremented: SCN guarantees the order of transactions
2. LGWR (Log Writer) writes remaining redo log to disk
3. LGWR writes SCN into the online redo log files
4. Transaction is removed from V$TRANSACTION
5. Locks of the actual session are released, removed from V$LOCK
6. Other sessions waiting for the locks of the actual session are notified
7. Block clean out may happen: Lock-related information is cleaned out of the block headers of the blocks modified by the transaction

Comment: What is the number 7? I have never heard of that.

Comment: The blocks modified by our transaction are cleaned out in a fast mode from the buffer cache. This clean out concerns the locking related information which is stored in the block header. I'll modify the answer with this info, thx for the comment.

Comment: Couple of points: The SCN must be generated at the start of the transaction, as it's used for consitency and to tag changes made. Also, "LGWR (Log Writer) writes redo log to disk" might have already been completed. As far as the log writer is concerned the only action that has to be completed as part of a commit is that the commit record for the transaction SCN be written to the redo log file. "Block clean out" is also not compulsory

Comment: I changed "SCN generated" to "SCN incremented". The question asks all internal processes, not only the compulsory ones. Thx